# Python - Trying to check input against range, then convert the variable into a string to be concatenated

Tags: python, string

first time posting here. I have searched high and low to figure out a way to do this, but I either don't understand how to apply existing answers to my code.

What I am trying to do is this: I want to take user input (a year), make sure it's between a range of years, and then if it is, concatenate it with an existing string as a variable.

The result of this code is that I get through and give all the necessary inputs, and then it fails with "fullInstr = str("cp -r /mnt/data/archive"+ fquery+ "/" + yquery+mquery+dquery+"/"+hquery+"*" + " " + outl2)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects"

```
import os
import sys

os.system("clear")
overW = str("0")

outf = str("/autocopy.sh") # Output file full path and file name
if os.path.isfile("/autocopy.sh"): #
 overW = raw_input("This will overwrite the previous version. Do you want to continue? (y/n) ")
 os.system("clear")
else:
 os.system("clear")

if overW != "y":
 os.system("clear")
 sys.exit("No changes made.\n\n")
else:
 os.system("clear")
  #! Could also prompt for output file name, depending on how army-proof this needs to be.

finishMessage = "Finished."

outl = str("0") # Copy-to location
outl2 = str("0") # Modified Copy-to location
fquery = str("0") # A or B location variable
yquery = int("0") # Year variable
mquery = int("0") # Month variable
dquery = int("0") # Day variable
hquery = str("0") # Hour variable
mh1 = int("0") # Modified starting hour after transformation
mh2 = int("0") # Modified ending hour after transformation
mpath = str("0") # makes path if needed
fullInstr = str("0") # Full command set to write to file
formatList = (['A', 'B'])
yearList = list(range(2000,2099))
#monthList = (['01']-['12'])
 #! hquery is going to have to parse for ranges

# Instruction header
print "Builds a script to automatically copy folders and files from the storage array to a location of your choosing.\n"
print "Valid inputs for the questions below are numeric."
print "Year would be the full year, i.e. 2013"
print "Month is the two-digit month, i.e. 10"
print "Day is the two-digit day, i.e. 22"
print "Hour or hour range is just the first two digits of the hours you want to copy. i.e. 15 or 00-23\n\n"

outl = raw_input("Where do you want to copy the files to? Type the full path: ")
while not os.path.exists(outl):
 mpath = raw_input ("\nThat path doesn't exist on this system. Do you want to create it? (y/n) ")
 if mpath != "y":
  outl = raw_input("Where do you want to copy the files to? Type a valid path: ")
 else:
  os.mkdir(outl)
  print "\n"

if not outl.endswith("/"):
 outl2 = outl + "/"

fquery = raw_input("Do you want to copy A or B? ")
while not(fquery in formatList):
 print "\nInvalid input. You have to choose one of the two as printed above."
 fquery = raw_input("\nDo you want to copy A or B? ")
 print "\n"

yquery = int(raw_input("What year? "))
while yquery not in yearList:
 print "\nInvalid input. You have to choose a year in this century."
 yquery = int(raw_input("\nWhat year? "))
 print "\n"

mquery = raw_input("What day? ")
 #! Valid months are 01 to 12 
dquery = raw_input("What day? ")
 #! Valid days are 01 to 31
hquery = raw_input("What hour or hour range? ")
 #! if input is greater than two characters is must contain a - character
 #! if is not 00-23, separate first and last numbers and write a line for each. If it isn't a range, don't transform it.

#os.system("touch " + outf)
 #! if no error keep going

fullInstr = str("cp -r /mnt/data/archive"+ fquery+ "/" + yquery+mquery+dquery+"/"+hquery+"*" + " " + outl2)

os.system("echo "+fullInstr+ "> /autocopy.sh")


#os.system("chmod u+x "+outf) # Makes the output file executable
 #! if error = 0 set finishMessage to print "Your shell script is complete and is ready to run. Run it by typing ." + outf
 #! if error is <> 0 set finishMessage to print "Wasn't able to make the output file executable automatically. Use chmod to modify the file permissions manually on the file "+outf

#os.system("clear")

print finishMessage+"\n\n"
```

Stuff that is commented out is either not working or not implemented yet. I know the code quality is probably not the best, but this is my first time coding to do something I require. I have tried a lot of things like yquery = str(yquery) or just changing the fullInstr string to have str(yquery) in it and I can not get it to work. I am becoming frustrated.

Comment: You are using `os.system()` at places where it is not needed. Do things on your own if possible; if not possible, at least use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: E.g., replace `os.system("echo "+fullInstr+ "> /autocopy.sh")` with `with open('autocopy.sh', 'w') as outfile: outfile.write(fullinstr + '\n')`

Comment: If user answers "yes" to continue the code exists, otherwise it continues.

Comment: @Jblasco s/exists/exits/.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have to admit, I haven't finished going through my python materials (MIT OCW, Khan Academy, and Google along with several other text resources) so I am not sure 100% what is deemed the correct way to accomplish things just yet. I ended up having to do something in a hurry and wish I had dedicated more time to learning before trying to do this quickly.

Comment: Also, thanks glglgl, I used this and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `format` for string formatting to avoid worrying about the type of variable being concatenated.

```
fullInstr = "cp -r /mnt/data/archive/{0}/{1}{2}{3}/{4}* {5}".format(fquery,yquery,mquery,dquery,hquery,out12)
```

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy Hi srinivas. To be frank I'm not able to place you. You were in which team? And I guess this is not an appropriate place to chat: others users will get confused and won't the OP get flooded with false notifications? :D

Comment: that won't happen. :). I was in Symphony - C#/Java team.I used to sit opposite ramana. will send a linkedin request. @sudipta

Comment: This worked for me and I found another little problem that I was able to fix. Thanks for the help Sudipta!

Answer (score 3):

That is because you need to convert the `int` to a `str` object.

```
    fullInstr = str("cp -r /mnt/data/archive" + fquery + "/" + str(yquery) + mquery + dquery + "/" + hquery + "*" + " " +                                      ^
                    outl2)                                      ^ 
#                                                               ^ -> Use str to convert
```

The above code worked on my machine. Running windows 8. Python 2.7.5. I just had to change `clear` to `cls`.

Comment: I tried this before I posted and it wouldn't work for me. I am on 2.7.2 on OS X, but the target system is 2.4.3 on CentOS.

Comment: @RyanShuck Update your python then. Its going on 2.7.5 now.